# Como colocar imagenes en HTML desde la raiz del proyecto (Angular)

Tags: html, angular, imagen

Quiero colocar una imagen en mi componente HTML en Angular.
Tengo el siguiente código en HTML:

```
 <div class="icon">
    <img class="image" alt="logo" src="/src/assets/images/logo-desktop.svg"/>
  </div>
```

La imagen se encuentra en esa dirección pero no la logra encontrar.
También probé sin el `/` inicial:

```
 <div class="icon">
    <img class="image" alt="logo" src="src/assets/images/logo-desktop.svg"/>
  </div>
```

Mi distribución de carpetas es la siguiente:

```
-src
    -app
        -components
            -navbar
                -navbar.component.html
                -...
    -assets
        -images
            -logo-desktop.svg
```

Sé que una solución es partir de la ruta base:

```
  <div class="icon">
    <img class="image" alt="bimtrazer-logo" src="./../../../assets/images/logo-desktop.svg" />
  </div>
```

En ese caso lo importa correctamente, el problema es que no me gusta la forma de leerse esto y si en el futuro cambio el lugar de la imagen sería medio complejo localizarla así.

Answer (score 0):

Para hacerlo usa el siguiente codigo

```
<div class="icon"> 
<img class="image" alt="bimtrazer-logo" src="assets/images/logo-desktop.svg"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).